# skew correction of document images research paper and test set

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, skew

is there any research paper available with implementation and large data set to find the skew angle of an image using opencv an python?
I have tried using houghline to detect skew angle of each line but i need large data set to validate error rate before using this implementation

```
def rotate_img(img_before, file_location):
    mean_angles = []
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_before, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 115, 2)
    img_edges = auto_canny(img_threshold)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img_edges, 1, math.pi / 180.0, 100, minLineLength=100, 
        maxLineGap=10)
    angles = []
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
                if -30 <= angle <= 30:
                    if angle != 0:
                        angles.append(angle)

                if 60 <= angle or angle <= -60:
                    if angle > 0:
                        angles.append(angle - 90)
                    else:
                        angles.append(angle + 90)

    if len(angles) > 10:
        mean_angle = statistics.mean(angles)
    else:
        mean_angle = 0

    return mean_angle
```

Comment: @nathancy my code above is working good but I need a large data set of skewed documents images to verify error rate. If you have such data set then send me the link